# Mouse stopped working under my OS (Kubuntu). Seems to work everywhere else

Tags: usb, kubuntu, mouse

I have a mouse that doesn't work correctly with my current OS (Kubuntu 16.04 / 64bit). After I press the change-DPI button the mouse stops working. After I unplug and replug it to the USB port, it starts to work again fine, sometimes only the buttons work but the cursor won't move. Currently no matter which USB port I plug it into or if I do a restart, only the buttons work and the cursor won't move. (When I press the change-DPI button it stops working completely.)

It works on this same machine perfectly under Win7 and in the BIOS too. I tried to live-boot several Linux versions (Kubuntu 17.10, Linux Mint 18.3. both 64 bit) and it worked under those fine (as long as I don't press the change-DPI button.) It also works on my laptop on Win7.

It seems like my current system remembers this mouse and it just doesn't want to work with it anymore. If I could make it work again (even without using the DPI button) that would be OK for me.

The mouse: Cougar 450M.
My motherboard: ASUS P-8Z77-M

I'm no expert with Linux, so I can't even guess whats wrong. I ran "lsusb -v" and this seems to be the info about the mouse:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12cf:0308 DEXIN 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x12cf DEXIN
  idProduct          0x0308 
  bcdDevice            0.16
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           84
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      75
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     174
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      26
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1554471

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks for the link! In my case when I'm running ubuntu in live mode, it always works. And initially it worked on the installed system too. Maybe it installed/configured some (broken) drivers for it and now it keeps using that. Wish I could reset it somehow